# Barra de progresso em upload de arquivos e cadastro de informações

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto, em que uso upload de arquivos, além de um cadastro de informações. Tanto o arquivo quanto as informações são cadastradas em um mesmo formulário. Até ai tudo bem, mas é que geralmente, quando há arquivo maiores, demora cerca de 20 a 30 segundos realizando o upload. As vezes demora até mais, e no momento o projeto não tem nada que indique o progresso de upload ao usuário. Logo, dependendo do usuário, o mesmo pode pensar que não aconteceu nada, e recarregar a página. Dessa forma, eu queria saber como colocar uma barra de progresso, modal, ou qualquer coisa, que informe ao usuário que o upload está sendo realizado. Como fazer isso?

Comment: Já há perguntas no site que resolvem este problema. Procuraste por elas? encontraste alguma que te ajudasse ou parecida?

Comment: Desculpe, mas pra essa categoria não encontrei nenhuma que me desse uma luz. Nem mesmo na versão inglês do site @Sergio

Comment: Dá uma olhada [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=barra+progresso). Mas de facto não há muita coisa com ASP...

Comment: Favoritei. Já posso adiantar que a solução envolve usar [Backload](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Backload/) e um pacote de upload tipo o [jQuery File Upload Plugin](http://www.nuget.org/packages/JQuery_File_Upload_Plugin/). Depois escrevo uma resposta pra você.

Comment: Ok @CiganoMorrisonMendez. Estarei aguardando. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu tambem precisei colocar algum indicador de atividade na minha aplicação asp.net, eu consegui usando o jQuery BlockUi.

Ele bloqueia a página para o usuário não clicar e exibe alguma imagem, gif, mensagem para que o mesmo saiba que ele esta trabalhando durante os PostBacks.

http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#page

Abraço.

Answer (score 1):

O que você precisa é adicionar um overlay (gif) [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] enquanto seu formulário estiver sendo enviado, e ocultar esse overlay quando o carregamento da página for concluído.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").prepend('<div id="overlay" class="ui-widget-overlay" style="z-index: 1001; display: none;"></div>');
    $("body").prepend("<div id='aguarde' style='display: none;'><img src='/imagens/loading.gif'/></div>");
});

$('#formulario').submit(function() {
    $("#overlay, #aguarde").show();

    return true;
});
```

*Adaptado da resposta em inglês https://stackoverflow.com/a/8140976/1639385*